# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException in Junit test

Tags: java, spring

I have such field in my bean class

```
@Value("#{${credentials}}")
private Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();
```

Here is its value in application.properties

```
credentials={customUser:"Pass"}
```

It works well when I run my spring boot application, but in JUnit tests I recieve bean creating error because of:

```
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

UPDATE:
Adding the default empty entryset solved the problem
@Value("#{${credentials:{:}}}")

Comment: In which context are you using `lcurly({)` ?

Comment: Didn't quite understand the question

Comment: In the error that you have posted, `lcurly({)` has been mentioned. Is that something that you are using in your code?

Comment: No, I guess it is about a curly brace in the file application.properties or in @Value("#{${credentials}}") expression

Comment: I did not find any issue running with the current code. Not sure why you needed the default value.

Comment: Actualy I don't need the default value, but this is workaround by which the problem was solved. Nevertheless, I would like to understand how to do it without default value.

Comment: I tried your code `@Value("#{${credentials}}")` and it worked without the default value. Which version of spring are you using? Maybe updating to the latest version might be enough.

Comment: I have the same issue. But adding the default value in my bean leads to an empty map. So that I get a NullPointerExeption at runtime in my bean